# New Item Form in blank ASPX page getting error

Tags: 2010

SharePoint 2010

Using SPD, I've created a blank .aspx page and inserted fields as 'new item form' from my list.  However, when I complete the form and hit save I get an error "The data source control failed to execute the insert command".  Am I missing something?

The steps I have taken to create the new form:
1. Click between form tags
2. Insert > Empty Data View
3. from Source Details, select fields and insert as 'new item form'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple reasons you might be getting this

- missing required fields
- this

> SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List"

should be

```
SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem"
```

- Make sure you have an "i" for insert in the databind rather than "u"

> SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit"
>   FieldName="kkk"
>   __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@kkk')}"
>   /

- possible bug. consider upgrading to sp2

references

http://thearkfloats.blogspot.se/2014/03/sharepoint-2010-data-source-control.html

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ae910269-3a0c-4506-844b-e8bc89d95b71/data-source-control-failed-to-execute-the-insert-command?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Perfect - thanks!!  The second bullet point is what I needed.  Interestingly, when I did a search on this I found everyone was saying to do the opposite, that is to REMOVE "Item" from "ListItem"..or I could have been reading the suggstions incorrectly.  Anyways, it worked and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, attachment name may be too long. Attachment name should not exceed 260 characters.